# WooCommerce Variation Image upload Issue Basel Theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce

[image]I am using Basel theme by xtemos, while using the variations i have encountered a problem where the image is not uploading on click.
i have checked all the possible things to check its compatibility with theme and plugins.
also tested this with storefront but the issue is

`` 12The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. 2meta-boxes-product-variation.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: wp.media.controller.Library is not a constructor at HTMLAnchorElement.add_image (meta-boxes-product-variation.min.js:1:7690) at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43184) at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41168) 5meta-boxes-product-variation.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: wp.media.controller.Library is not a constructor at HTMLAnchorElement.add_image (meta-boxes-product-variation.min.js:1:7690) at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43184) at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41168) add_image @ meta-boxes-product-variation.min.js:1 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2 y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2 DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/js/companionBubble.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT ``

Comment: This seems an error generated by your browser that is blocking a resource due to some enabled add-on (extension): "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT". Try to change of browser (without extensions).

Comment: Tried this on 3-4 browser but same error

Comment: Then you should open a support ticket in Basel theme's Author pages. But before, make a backup, disable all plugins except WooCommerce, to see if the error is still there. If not, a plugin is involved. If the error is still there, try to switch the theme to something else like the Storefront theme, to see if the error is still there. if the error is not anymore there the issue comes from theme.